# how to display other table data in $row = mysql_fetch_row

Tags: php, sql, row

I have 3 tables: `te_event`, `te_venue`, `te_category`.

- `te_event` table has columns: `categoryID`, `venueID`, `event description`, `title`, `date`, `price`.
- `te_venue` table has columns: `venueID`, `venueName` and `location`.
- `te_category` has columns: `catID` and `catDesc`.

and here is my sql query:

```
$sqlEvent =" SELECT * FROM te_events 
                 INNER JOIN te_venue ON te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID 
                 INNER JOIN te_category ON te_events.catID = te_category.catID
                 WHERE eventID =" .$id;
```

If I use `row[]` to retrieve data from `te_events`, the `row[ *number]` depends on the `te_events` column.
So how do I retrieve other table data by using `row[*number]`?

Comment: What does `other data` mean?

Comment: te_events only shows the venueID and catID
i want to shows the venueName and catDesc instead of the venueID and catID @Benyi

Comment: If you use `*` in `SELECT` as field, `INNER JOIN` will return all the fields that involved in. Would you please provide what SQL server returns?

Comment: i want to retrieve it from database to my php page actually.

Comment: I know that. That's what I'm answering. I mean what the data you get from the database? Would you please paste some raw result? Perhaps it's about PHP not SQL statement.

Comment: it do show up the result i want.
but when i update certain information, it shows SQL ERROR :Unknown column 'catDesc' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if that will answer your question which is pretty confuse...

Once you fetch the results in `$row`, it contains data from the 3 tables because that's what your SQL query returns.

So to get data from `te_event` :

```
$categoryID = $row['categoryID'];
$title= $row['title'];
...
```

And to get data from  `te_venue` :

```
$categoryID = $row['venueName'];
$location= $row['location'];
...
```

But ideally you should only retrieve the columns you need in the code, and alias some of them :

```
$sqlEvent =" SELECT * 
                 te_events.categoryID, te_events.venueID, te_events.`event description` AS eventdesc, te_events.title, te_events.date, te_events.price, 
                 te_venue.venueName , te_venue.location,
                 te_category.catDesc
             FROM te_events 
             INNER JOIN te_venue ON te_events.venueID = te_venue.venueID 
             INNER JOIN te_category ON te_events.catID = te_category.catID
             WHERE eventID =" .$id;
```

Also you should use a parametrized query to pass your `$id` and prevent SQL injection.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.
i want to retrive all the events details by showing the venuaName,location or category instead of venueID or catID.